# Cannot filter by artifactSourceId in Azure DevOps API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Given a known buildDefinitionId I am attempting to determine the (one or more) Release Definitions that depend on the output of the build.

The docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

state that I can pass in an `artifactSourceId` parameter in the format `{projectGuid}:{BuildDefinitionId}` however when I try to pass in this parameter I get *every* release definition for the specified project.

Using the url : `https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/my-company/d4155bbc-d85f-4aaf-9a8e-0ba70272cca4/_apis/release/definitions?artifactSourceId=d4155bbc-d85f-4aaf-9a8e-0ba70272cca4:950&api-version=5.0`

In my project I get a list of 553 build definitions. Searching in the response body for the artifact key `d4155bbc-d85f-4aaf-9a8e-0ba70272cca4:950` ({projectGuid}:{buildDefinitionId}) gives me the expected 2 results as per below:

```
"artifacts": [
            {
                "sourceId": "d4155bbc-d85f-4aaf-9a8e-0ba70272cca4:950",
                "type": "Build",
                "alias": "my-build-definition",
                // more fields here
             }
             ]
```

Curiously if I don't pass in the `artifactSourceId` parameter, I don't get any artifact data in the response at all - including when I specify the `$expand=artifact` parameter - but I can specify `artifactSourceId=xyz` and it will still return a list of **all** release definitions.

This seems like it could be a bug with the api, but if anyone has any insight or workarounds I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parameter `$expand=artifacts` (not `$expand=artifact`) to expand artifacts details.

Regarding parameter `artifactSourceId`, you need to use parameters `artifactType` and `artifactSourceId`together to filter the Release definitions with given artifactSourceId.

Comment: Great - thanks very much. `$expand=artifacts` was a typo on my part, but (based on the MSFT in your name) it would be useful to specify that you need an artifactType in the docs